# SIMD - How do you pre-heat an array pointer with loadu?

Tags: c++, c, intel, simd, intrinsics

Lets say we have an array of chars and we want to pre-process (first-pass) the algorithm, to align it to 16bytes. From what I have gathered online (scarce info), you check if the data is 16bytes aligned, if not you use loadu and pre-pass your algorithm, then move the array pointer like so:

```
str = (const char *)(0x10 + (intptr_t)str & ~0xF);
```

Great, we get the previous 16byte aligned address, then add 16 to that, boom!

But from what I see, some data will be processed twice! Or is loadu intelligent and only loads data from [unaligned addr] to [next aligned addr]?

It seems it doesn't :
"Load 128-bits of integer data from memory into dst. mem_addr does not need to be aligned on any particular boundary. "

So how do you pre-pass your algorithm then?

Thanks a ton, please bear with me while I learn SIMD :)

Comment: If you can't guarantee that your data is properly aligned then just use unaligned loads - the penalty is virtually zero on modern CPUs.

Comment: Interesting! So all this pain for nothing? :D

Comment: It's mainly historical - older CPUs incurred a significant penalty for misaligned loads, which is probably why you see a lot of out-of-date advice on the web about dealing with misaligned data. (NB: I'm assuming we're talking about x86 here - ARM and PowerPC are a different story.)

Comment: If I may diverge a bit, what do you use for the last data? Do you finish your loop with a traditional non-simd pass? Or maybe cast the simd pointer to a (ex) uint8_t*, then access the valid elements like an array? Thx! Yes it is x86.

Comment: Aligned data accesses perform better than unaligned ones. But on modern CPUs the overhead of implementing different code paths for both possibilities is not worth it. _That's good news :-)_ Except for the SIMD instructions that _require_ aligned data.

Comment: @scx: well, it depends - often you can mask the residual vector (padding the data helps). Also  if your algorithm allows it you can do an overlapped vector at the end. Scalar clean up loops are OK if your data length is large enough that the cost becomes insignificant, but can be problematic if your data consists of only a few vectors.

Comment: This has been really insightful. Thanks both of you for your time, truly appreciated.

Comment: @PaulR I've found that masked moves are quite underrated in eliminating clean up loops. It's a trick I discovered a couple years ago while looking at some ICC-generated AVX512. But I only recently found that it's workable with AVX2.

Comment: @Mysticial: interesting - thanks - I haven't played with masked moves much, but I'll take a look. Throughout is 6-7 though on current CPUs ?

Comment: @PaulR Throughput is 2/1 for load/store on Haswell and 0.5/1 on Skylake. (i.e. as fast as normal load/store on Skylake) The latencies are high though, but that shouldn't matter if you're looping through memory and will beat a scalar loop anyway. The idea is that you iterate your vectorized loop until the # of remaining iterations drops below the vector size. Then you construct an index vector and `vcmpgtd/q` it with the stop-index to get a mask of which lanes are needed to finish the loop. Then run the vectorized loop body one more time, but with masked load/stores.

Comment: @Mysticial: thanks - I'm looking at the Intel Intrinsics Guide for timing and it says 6 or 7 cycles for throughput, with no figures for latency - I'm wondering if those are actually meant to be latency numbers though, based on what you say...

Comment: From what I tested, the non-temporal memory hit is really what hurts performance with maskmove (trashing cashes). But, if it's your last iteration, then trashing the cashes might not be an issue. It sounds like a good solution to me.